# MVC 4 Dropdown validation

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, unobtrusive-validation

OK, this is driving me nuts. I've got an MVC 4 website that is validating textboxes on the client, but not the dropdowns.

My (cut-down) model looks like this:

```
[Required]
public int? FabricOptionSelected { get; set; }
public List<SelectListItem> FabricOptions { get; private set; }
```

My (cut-down) controller looks like this:

```
model.FabricOptions.AddRange(product.Options
.Where(a=>a.ProductOptionCategory == Domain.Products.ProductOptionCategory.Fabric)
.ToSelectList( m => m.Name, m => m.Id.ToString(), "-- Select --"));
```

My (cut-down) view looks like this:

```
@if (Model.FabricOptions.Count > 1)
    {
        <div class="row form-group">
            <div class="col-xs-2 control-label">Fabric</div>
            <div class="col-xs-4">@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.FabricOptionSelected, Model.FabricOptions, new { @class = "form-control" })</div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FabricOptionSelected)</div>
        </div>
    }
```

I have "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js", and "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js" in my bundle config and the web.config has :

```
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
```

in the appsettings section.

Chrome console is not showing any errors and there is a text box with the Required attribute further down the page that is being fired.

.ToSelectList is an extension method:

```
public static List<SelectListItem> ToSelectList<T>
        (this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, 
        Func<T, string> text, 
        Func<T, string> value, 
        string defaultOption)
    {
        var items = enumerable.Select(f => new SelectListItem() { Text = text(f), Value = value(f) }).ToList();
        items.Insert(0, new SelectListItem() { Text = defaultOption, Value = "-1" });
        return items;
    }
```

Can't figure out why the client-side validation in the view isn't firing for the drop-downs. I figure I'm missing something obvious but could really do with a hand on this one.

Comment: you have the required attribute on fabric options selected but it is nullable so if they haven't chosen anything I would think it would still be valid.  Try removing the nullable to see if that makes a difference

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks for the reply. Tried that - no luck.

Comment: What is `.ToSelectList`? You do not appear to be rendering a `null` option so something is always selected so its valid and you would never get an error message.

Comment: Hi Stephen, it's an extension method. I've updated my original question to show it

Comment: Not sure why your not just using the default select list and helper that renders an option label (far easier) but your extension method is adding a "default" option with `value=-1`. Since `-1` is an int (not a null value) its valid so there is no error.

Comment: Hi Stephen, could you elaborate please? Maybe I'm over complicating it..

Comment: Your extension method is not really doing anything that the inbuilt MVC methods don't already do. I'll post an answer showing how it would be done without the extension method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure `.ToSelectList` (is this an extension you added?) sets the default `-- Select --` value to `null`. Setting it to a nullable type is a good start but it needs to be null for Required to work.

Comment: Ah, bingo. I changed the extension from items.Insert(0, new SelectListItem() { Text = defaultOption, Value = "-1" }); to items.Insert(0, new SelectListItem() { Text = defaultOption, Value = null }); and made the int nullable again. It worked a treat! Can't believe that was the problem, but thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your extension method is inserting a "default" option which has a `value="-1"` which is valid for an `int` therefore there will be no error. You can achieve want you want using methods already available in MVC

Model

```
[Required]
public int? FabricOptionSelected { get; set; }
public SelectList FabricOptions { get; set; }
```

Controller

```
var option = product.Options.Where(a=>a.ProductOptionCategory == Domain.Products.ProductOptionCategory.Fabric);
model.FabricOptions = new SelectList(options, "ID", "Name");
```

View

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.FabricOptionSelected, Model.FabricOptions, "-- Select --", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

The 3rd parameter renders the first option of the `<select>` as `<option value>--Select--</option>` i.e. without a value so if that is selected, `int? FabricOptionSelected` will be `null` and therefore fail validation because of the `[Required]` attribute

Comment: Ahh, thanks Stephen. Tried it out and it works great. This would seem to be a better way to go rather than introducing self-made bugs. Always better to utilize the (well tested) framework. Thanks for your help